# How do I add bubbles on each of the y-axis values that I have and how do I add mouseover function for each of them?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization, linechart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none ;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;

}

    #legend {
        margin-left:220px;
    }
</style>
<div id="legend">
    <h3>Cholera No Of Deaths & Cases</h3>
 
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="legend.js"></script>
<script>
var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var y1= d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y1)
        .orient("right").ticks(5);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

    var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function (d) { return y1(d.value2); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("country.json", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d)
        {
            d.year   = parseDate(d.year.toString());
            d.value  = +d.value;
            d.value2 = +d.value2;
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.year; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
        y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value2; })]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
          .attr("x", 265)
          .attr("y", 240)
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("Years");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Number Of Cholera Cases");

         svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis1)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ',0)');

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
             .style("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", line(data));

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")

            .attr("d", line2(data));

        legend = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,30)")
      .style("font-size", "12px")
      .call(d3.legend);

        setTimeout(function () {
            legend
              .style("font-size", "20px")
              .attr("data-style-padding", 10)
              .call(d3.legend)
        }, 1000)




    });

</script></div>
```

The below is the graph that I have created using the codes above but I would like to add a bubbles for each of the y-axis values and have a mouseover function to show the exact value of the y-axis. So, how would I need to change my code so that there will be a bubble on each of the y-axis value and a mouseover function? Lastly, how would I need to change my code so that there will be a option where I can change the y-axis using a radio button to show only one of the value at a time. The example below shows what I am trying to use for my codes. http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html

```
[{"country":"Singapore","year": "1993", "value":"37046", "value2": "931"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1994", "value":"38735", "value2": "118"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1995", "value":"19903", "value2": "624"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1997", "value":"4170", "value2": "125"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1998", "value":"10000", "value2": "0"}]
```

The above is the JSON file that I am using.

[image: Line Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example utilizing a mouseover function defined by d3.caged. Check to see the dependencies that are added you'll notice that the solution is very similar to this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

Here's your solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/blakedietz/H5HB9/3/

```
var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) 
     return "<strong>Blah:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value + "</span>";
  });

var tip1 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Blah:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value2 + "</span>";
  });


var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var y1= d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1)
    .orient("right").ticks(5);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function (d) { return x(d.year); })
.y(function (d) { return y1(d.value2); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 svg.call(tip).call(tip1);

    var data = [{"country":"Singapore","year": "1960", "value":"887", "value2": "199"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1965", "value":"218", "value2": "55"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1993", "value":"37046", "value2": "931"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1994", "value":"38735", "value2": "118"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1995", "value":"19903", "value2": "624"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1997", "value":"4170", "value2": "125"},
{"country":"Singapore","year": "1998", "value":"10000", "value2": "0"}];

    data.forEach(function (d)
    {
        d.year   = parseDate(d.year.toString());
        d.value  = +d.value;
        d.value2 = +d.value2;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.year; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
    y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value2; })]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
      .attr("x", 265)
      .attr("y", 240)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Years");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Number Of Cholera Cases");

     svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis1)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ',0)');

    svg.selectAll('.yaxis1')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'yaxis1')
            .attr('cx', function(datum){return x(datum.year)})
            .attr('cy', function(datum){return y(datum.value)})
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('fill', 'red')
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    svg.selectAll('.yaxis2')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'yaxis2')
            .attr('cx', function(datum){return x(datum.year)})
            .attr('cy', function(datum){return y1(datum.value2)})
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('fill', 'blue') 
            .on('mouseover', tip1.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip1.hide);

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
         .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("d", line(data));

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")

        .attr("d", line2(data));

    legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,30)")
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .call(d3.legend);

    setTimeout(function () {
        legend
          .style("font-size", "20px")
          .attr("data-style-padding", 10)
          .call(d3.legend)
    }, 1000)
```